# Javascript using bind without overwriting this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take this example that uses a "widgetManager" object to bind events to all accordions:

```
widgetManager = {
    name : 'widgetManager',
    initiate : function(){
        $('.accordion').accordion({
            onClosing : this.onCloseAccordion.bind(this.name),
        })
    },
    onCloseAccordion : function(){
        console.log(name); //I want the event to receive the manager name
        console.log(this); //But still be able to know which accordion was clicked
    }
}
widgetManager.initiate();
```

If I bind something to the accordion's `onClosing` event, it will lose to reference to itself (the accordion that is closing), but I also need a way to be able to pass the 'name' property to the function.

Maybe `bind` isn't what I'm looking for, but is there a simple way to solve this?

I guess a better wording is, how to pass an object to a function without overwriting the function's scope's `this`

I'm using Semantic UI's accordions if that helps or changes anything, but the event has no parameters https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/settings

Comment: If you think the question is duplicated or needs improvement, please tell me so

Comment: Should `this.onCloseAccordion` be `this.onClosing`?

Comment: @Barmar You're right, my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply refer to `widgetManager.name` to get the name.

```
widgetManager = {
    name : 'widgetManager',
    initiate : function(){
        var theManager = this;
        $('.accordion').accordion({
            onClosing : this.onCloseAccordion.bind(this),
        })
    },
    onClosing : function(){
        console.log(widgetManager.name); //I want the event to receive the manager name
        console.log(this); //But still be able to know which accordion was clicked
    }
}
widgetManager.initiate();
```

If you want something more general, you should be using a constructor function to create different managers.

```
function widgetManager(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.initiate = function() {
        $('.accordion').accordion({
            onClosing: this.onCloseAccordion.bind(this);
        });
        return this; // For fluent interface
    };
    this.onCloseAccordion = function() {
        console.log(name);
        console.log(this);
    };
};
```

Then you use it like this:

```
var theWidgetManager = new widgetManager("widgetManager");
theWidgetManager.initiate();
```